# Check permission for a user belonging in diff group in 2007

Tags: 2007, permissions, administration

In SP2010 we have an option to check user permission incase user has many permission levels. How do we achieve the same in SP2007? I did install Microsoft SharePoint Administration Toolkit for it as mentioned in microsoft site (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/check-permissions-for-a-user-or-group-HA010362860.aspx) but I cant see the option anywhere in Site setting.

Can anyone please help me incase I've missed something in between?

Thanks in advance,
Lav

Answer (score 1):

Check this tool on Codeplex: http://sushi.codeplex.com/

This can give you the security report. Works very well for SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try activating the feature for this using the stsadm command?

1.At the command prompt, run stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename “C:\Program Files\Microsoft\SPAdministrationToolkit\PermissionReporting\PermissionReporting.wsp” to add the solution file to the farm solution store.

2.Run stsadm.exe –o deploysolution –name PermissionReporting.wsp –immediate -allowgacdeployment to deploy the solution to the farm.

3.Run stsadm.exe –o activatefeature –name PermissionReporting to activate the feature.

For Detailed instructions [check this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508849%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I understood the issue later. We can perform permission management using Microsoft SharePoint Administration Toolkit. My mistake was that I copy pasted addsolution and deploysolution commands into command prompt resulting in toolkit not getting installed properly. FYI we'll need April CU for the toolkit to work properly

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to accomplish this out of the box either through the UI or with SharePoint Designer.

+1 for SharePoint SUSHI but we found it inadequate to our needs and decided that we needed to purchase a management tool. There are many available, all good and we settled on Axceler ControlPoint. Part of the reason to buy a tool instead of using SUSHI was the requirement to clone user permissions from one user to another in addition to the detailed reporting that you described.

Comment: I understood the issue later. We can perform permission management using Microsoft SharePoint Administration Toolkit. My mistake was that I copy pasted addsolution and deploysolution commands into command prompt resulting in toolkit not getting installed properly. FYI we'll need April CU for the toolkit to work properly.